# Javascript Named capturing groups regular expression issue when included in html

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Two snippets are shown below. The first one is pure Js and runs correctly with *node.js*
The second one is just a copy of it encapsulated into some Html page as the function *getDate*.
Surprisingly the html code gives the error *SyntaxError: invalid regexp group* at line 1. Why ?

```
    const re = /(?<year>\d{4})-(?<month>\d{2})-(?<day>\d{2})/
    const result = re.exec('2015-01-02')
    console.log(result);
    console.log('year', result.groups.year);
    console.log('month',result.groups.month);
    console.log('day',result.groups.day);
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <meta charset="utf8"/>
        <body>
     <button onclick="getDate()">Get Date</button>
     <script>
      function getDate() {
          const re = /(?<year>\d{4})-(?<month>\d{2})-(?<day>\d{2})/
          const result = re.exec('2015-01-02')
          console.log(result);
          console.log('year', result.groups.year);
          console.log('month',result.groups.month);
          console.log('day',result.groups.day);
      }
     </script>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your code snippet seems to run fine. What browser is giving you the problem? They are not all created equal.

Comment: @ Booboo  I use Firefox 68.7.0esr (64 bits) on Debian. It runs fine on Brave !

Comment: Nor does it work in Edge (but it does work in Chrome). This is why when I code JavaScript to be used in a browser, I code to the lowest common denominator, which is pretty low. Before you use a feature, check [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Browser_compatibility).